# Use of "this" in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I don't understand how does `this` works in the following code (extracted from a React tutorial):

```
class Connect extends React.Component {
    myFunc = event => {
        console.log(this.pseudoInput);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.myFunc(e)} >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudo" required ref={(input) => { this.pseudoInput = input }} />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If I understand well, `this` refers to the parent object (is the parent object is input here ?). But this parent object has no `pseudoInput` property. So I don't understand it's use. Could you tell me where I am wrong ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react we use `ref` to create references to components. As you can see that in above code, a ref is created for input.

`ref={(input) => { this.pseudoInput = input }}`

`this.pseudoInput` create a reference to the input by name of `pseudoInput` as assign it to the current class. And hence `console.log(this.pseudoInput);` 
will refer to the input component

Answer (score 0):

Variables don't need to be explicitly defined or initialized within a JS object.  The above code is pretty much the same as the following:

```
var test = {};
test.variableName = 'some value';
console.log(test.variableName); //outputs 'some value'
```